# Devise Redirect to Page After Sign In Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, devise, controller

I am on Rails 4.

I have it setup so when a user signs up or logs in (devise) it will redirect to the page they were last on. It works very nicely.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to ignore the admin completely. When signing in as an admin (admin is its own model), I receive a redirect loop, as it wants to go back to the previous page and the admin panel at the same time.

Here is my application_controller:

```
after_filter :store_location

  def store_location
    # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/ 
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end
```

What would be the best way to ignore the `after_sign_in_path_for` if it is an admin signing in?

Comment: admin is user object or not ?

Comment: Admin is its own model, so not a user object. @HaiderAli

Comment: which field are you using to check admin inside user model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to supply on route or another since we creating such a method in our application_controller. The simple solution would be the one below.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.admin? #Assuming there is such a function
    root_path
  else
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: replaced `resource.admin?` with `admin_signed_in?` and it worked like a charm.